# Checking annotation presence in subclasses with ArchUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, annotations, archunit

I'm evaluating ArchUnit 0.13.1 with JUnit 5 and try to write a rule like:

```
    @ArchTest
    private final ArchRule annotationInheritance = ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
            .that().areAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)
            .should().onlyHaveSubclassesThat().areAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

The problem is there is no method "onlyHaveSubclassesThat()" in ArchUnit.
I'm sure there is probably another way to achieve the same goal, but how?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the check to the subclasses that inherit a certain class:

```
classes()
    .that().areAssignableTo(CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class))
    .should().beAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```